# How to handle errors and exit in nested scripts?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a unix bash script 1 that calls script 2 and 2 calls 3A, 3B and 3C. Furthermore, if there is any error in execution of any of these scripts, I want to email QA.

Assuming I want to check if 3B ran successfully (and notify QA if there was a failure), should I check exit code after each command in 3B (which would be a lot of error handling) or can I just check if execution of 3B was successful as a whole from script 2 (i.e. the caller)? Another drawback with the first option is that I have to exit 3 times (i.e. 3B, 2, 1)

Comment: Please use capitalization, punctuation and paragraphs. Your wall of text is *incredibly* hard to read.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post twice, I am NOT sure how to word this question best. Please do not just close it or flag it because it's not a everyday routine/standard question.

Comment: The down votes were almost certainly for the formatting problems (but neither of them was mine). This is improved but still a wall of text. But further editing would yield many more improvements. Try to consolidate thoughts into units and use formatting to help make things clear. Code formatting for literals, lists for alternatives, etc.

Comment: @EtanReisner +1 for your patience! :)

Comment: @newrealtest0000 Your question is really broad! I will give you one sentence you need to know: Handle exceptions where you can really handle them, otherwise throw them - meaning return a non-zero exit code and print an error message on stderr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat each script as a self-contained program.  The calling script only cares whether the called script succeeded or failed.  So each script must return an accurate exit status — zero on success, non-zero on failure.

Inside `script1`, you have:

```
if script2
then : OK
else mailx -s "script2 failed inside script1" qa@example.com <<< EOM
     exit 1
fi
```

Inside `script2`, you have:

```
if ! script3A
then mailx -s "script3A failed inside script2" qa@example.com <<< EOM
     exit 1
elif ! script3B
then mailx -s "script3B failed inside script2" qa@example.com <<< EOM
     exit 1
elif ! script3C
then mailx -s "script3C failed inside script2" qa@example.com <<< EOM
     exit 1
else : OK
fi
```

You can consider using `set -e`, but then you have to worry about how to get the email to QA.

If you need to get standard output from the commands to QA, you have to work harder.
If you need to capture standard error to send to QA, then it gets harder again.

If you decide that you don't need to know exactly what failed, you can simplify the code, especially inside `script2`.

Comment: Well in the same case (3B failing), won't we send the email twice (once from script 2 and one from script 1)?

Comment: You will send two messages because two scripts failed.  They won't be the same message: one will say the 3B failed, and one will say that 2 failed.  You can work around that.  For example, you can simply decide that 2 won't report what failed by email if it is one of 3A, 3B or 3C that fails (but it will if it is something else that fails).  The choice is yours.

Comment: We are getting close.  That is exactly why I posted the question in first place: It seemed very inconsistent to me to selectively decide to send the email sometimes from script 2 and sometimes from 1 (not to mention I probably would need to send email from any of 3A, B and C too if any command  fails in them too). That's why I was wondering what would be the best/logical way.

Comment: I'd go with more emails.  If you don't want to go with more emails, then script1 won't report an error if script2 fails, and script2 will fail but not report an error if one of the script3x's fails.  You decide what you want to happen; then implement it.  What's crucial is that you relay and handle exit statuses accurately.  Where you report the errors is up to you, but you can usually give better details lower down the hierarchy.  If 3B fails, 3B should report what it was doing and exit with an error; 2 should recognize that 3B failed, not report anything, and exit with an error; …

Comment: Yup. I think that makes sense. I am going to send the failure notification at the lowest level. I still have to exit out of nested scripts all the way up to the highest level, but there is no work around for that. Thanks.